# although at least one Creator exists): no int/Int-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from Number value (1)

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson, jackson-databind

I'm getting the error when I'm trying to run the Application by selecting the option Spring Boot App.

: Cannot construct instance of `com.kafkamq.KafkaOrderDetails.entity.OrderDetails` (although at least one Creator exists): no int/Int-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from Number value (1)
at [Source: (String)"1"; line: 1, column: 1

```
package com.kafkamq.KafkaOrderDetails.entity;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table
public class OrderDetails {

@Id
private long id;

@Column(name = "desc")
private String desc;

@Column(name = "status")
private String status;

public long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getDesc() {
    return desc;
}

public void setDesc(String desc) {
    this.desc = desc;
}

public String getStatus() {
    return status;
}

public void setStatus(String status) {
    this.status = status;
}

public OrderDetails(long id, String desc, String status) {
    super();
    this.id = id;
    this.desc = desc;
    this.status = status;
}

public OrderDetails() {

}
```

The entity class is
The project is running fine with no errors in my friend system. But it's not even able to start in my system. What could be the problem? I'm also using Kafka in my project.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, the message means your class has no constructor taking a string instead of a long, please include the json causing this behaviour.